# react-table Reinitializing on Render

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I'm having an issue where react-table (version 7.1.0) seems to be reinitializing any time the page needs to be re-rendered. Using the code below ([running example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-cray-p8r9k)) as an example, if you were to change the pageIndex value (by switching to a different page), then hit Dummy Button, you can observe that the pageIndex resets back to its default value of 0. The same thing happens if you modify the pageSize in that it automatically resets back to its default value of 10 any time the page has to be re-rendered.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import makeData from "./makeData";
import { useTable, usePagination } from "react-table";
import { ButtonToolbar, Button, Table } from "react-bootstrap";

// Nonsense function to force page to be rendered
function useForceUpdate() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  return () => setValue(value => ++value);
}

export default function App() {
  const forceUpdate = useForceUpdate();
  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Name",
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "First Name",
            accessor: "firstName"
          },
          {
            Header: "Last Name",
            accessor: "lastName"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        Header: "Info",
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "Age",
            accessor: "age"
          },
          {
            Header: "Visits",
            accessor: "visits"
          },
          {
            Header: "Status",
            accessor: "status"
          },
          {
            Header: "Profile Progress",
            accessor: "progress"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  const data = React.useMemo(() => makeData(100000), []);
  let ArchiveTable = ({ columns, data }) => {
    const {
      getTableProps,
      getTableBodyProps,
      headerGroups,
      prepareRow,
      page,
      canPreviousPage,
      canNextPage,
      pageOptions,
      pageCount,
      gotoPage,
      nextPage,
      previousPage,
      setPageSize,
      state: { pageIndex, pageSize }
    } = useTable(
      {
        columns,
        data
      },
      usePagination
    );

    return (
      <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        <Table striped bordered {...getTableProps()} className="datasets">
          <thead>
            {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
              <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                  <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                    {column.render("Header")}
                  </th>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </thead>
          <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
            {page.map((row, i) => {
              prepareRow(row);

              return (
                <tr
                  {...row.getRowProps()}
                  className={row.isSelected ? "selected" : row.className}
                >
                  {row.cells.map(cell => {
                    return (
                      <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
                    );
                  })}
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
        <div className="pagination" style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>
          <ButtonToolbar>
            <Button
              variant="light"
              onClick={() => gotoPage(0)}
              disabled={!canPreviousPage}
              size="small"
            >
              <span>&lt;&lt;</span>
            </Button>
            <Button
              variant="light"
              onClick={previousPage}
              disabled={!canPreviousPage}
              size="small"
            >
              <span>&lt;</span>
            </Button>
            <select
              value={pageSize}
              onChange={e => {
                setPageSize(Number(e.target.value));
              }}
            >
              {[5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50].map(pageSize => (
                <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
                  Show {pageSize}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
            <Button
              variant="light"
              onClick={nextPage}
              disabled={!canNextPage}
              size="small"
            >
              <span>&gt;</span>
            </Button>
            <Button
              variant="light"
              onClick={() => gotoPage(pageCount - 1)}
              disabled={!canNextPage}
              size="small"
            >
              <span>&gt;&gt;</span>
            </Button>
          </ButtonToolbar>
          <span>
            Page <strong>{pageOptions.length === 0 ? 0 : pageIndex + 1}</strong>{" "}
            of <strong>{pageOptions.length}</strong>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ArchiveTable data={data} columns={columns} />
      <button onClick={forceUpdate}>Dummy Button</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm at a complete loss for what to do to fix this. What is the proper way to set everything up so that I don't reinitialize react-table every time the page has to be re-rendered? Said another way, if I hit the Dummy Button, I don't want the table to reset back to page 1 with a page size of 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring out the answer. The problem was I needed to move the initialization of the table outside of the rendering logic (quite obvious, in hindsight). Basically, I simply created an ArchiveTable function. For anybody who stumbles across this, you can [check here](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-glade-w4o4x) for a working example.

```
function ArchiveTable({ columns, data }) {
    // Add all the initialization and table rendering code here
    // (everything that was originally part of the ArchiveTable initialization)
}
```